# Is WeakHashMap ever-growing, or does it clear out the garbage keys?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weakhashmap

I am trying to use [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) as a concurrent [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of weak references.

```
    this.subscribers =
            Collections.synchronizedSet(
                    Collections.newSetFromMap(
                            new WeakHashMap <>()
                    )
            );
```

When an element goes to garbage-collection, my set continues to report it as a part of the collection. So it seems the map is ever-growing.

The documentation says:

> When a key has been discarded its entry is effectively removed from the map,…

But that does not seem to be the case in practice.

Is there ever a point at which the `WeakHashMap` clears out the detritus?

Comment: "When an element goes to garbage-collection, my set continues to report it as a part of the collection" - how are you determining this?

Comment: @user2357112 I am calling `Set::size()`.

Comment: "This result is a snapshot, and may not reflect unprocessed entries that will be removed before next attempted access because they are no longer referenced."

Comment: Also, how are you determining that those objects have been garbage collected?

Comment: @user2357112 Indeed I must have been wrong in assuming the objects were garbage-collected. See my posted Answer with a small experiment showing that the `Set` reports it size declining whether due to calling `Set::remove` or due to becoming garbage. I will have to explore my original code problem more thoroughly.

Comment: Related: [*Why WeakHashMap holds strong reference to value after GC?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34878160/642706)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, keys cleared *after* garbage is actually collected

**Yes, `WeakHashMap` does clean out the detritus.** The keys that have gone to garbage collection are no longer reported in the size. But you must wait for garbage-collection to actually take place.

Seems likely that you were incorrect about your objects going to garbage-collection. Perhaps your objects became *candidates* for garbage-collection, but have not yet been collected. Try invoking the garbage-collector and waiting a moment for it to complete. But remember, the call to `System.gc()` is only a suggestion to the JVM and may be ignored depending on your JVM implementation and current runtime scenario.

Here is a complete example app. Notice that the `Set` reports a decrease in `size` whether calling `Set::remove` or letting the object go out of scope.

```
package com.basilbourque.example;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;

public class WeakHashMapExercise {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        WeakHashMapExercise app = new WeakHashMapExercise();
        app.doIt();
    }

    private void doIt ( ) {
        Set < UUID > set =
                Collections.synchronizedSet(
                        Collections.newSetFromMap(
                                new WeakHashMap <>()
                        )
                );

        UUID uuid1 = UUID.fromString( "a8ee1e34-cead-11e8-a8d5-f2801f1b9fd1" );
        UUID uuid2 = UUID.fromString( "39bda2b4-5885-4f56-a900-411a49beebac" );
        UUID uuid3 = UUID.fromString( "0b630385-0452-4b96-9238-20cdce37cf55" );
        UUID uuid4 = UUID.fromString( "98d2bacf-3f7f-4ea0-9c17-c91f6702322c" );

        System.out.println( "Size before adding: " + set.size() );

        set.add( uuid1 );
        set.add( uuid2 );
        set.add( uuid3 );
        set.add( uuid4 );

        System.out.println( "Size after adding 4 items: " + set.size() );  // Expect 4.

        set.remove( uuid3 );

        System.out.println( "Size after removing item # 3: " + set.size() );  // Expect 3.

        uuid2 = null;  // Release that UUID to garbage-collection.

        // That released object may still appear in our `Set` until garbage collection actually executes. 
        System.gc(); // Ask the JVM to run the garbage-collection. Only a suggestion, may be ignored.
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 1_000 );  // Wait a moment, just for the heck of it.
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "Size after making garbage of item # 2: " + set.size() );  // Expect 2.

        for ( UUID uuid : set ) {
            System.out.println( uuid.toString() );
        }


    }
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/UZmwny).

> Size before adding: 0
>
> Size after adding 4 items: 4
>
> Size after removing item # 3: 3
>
> Size after making garbage of item # 2: 2

In my case, using [Java 10.0.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10) version of [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)-based [Zulu JVM](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/) from [Azul Systems](https://www.azul.com), the garbage collector does seem to be activating upon my request. If I comment out the delay for a second, or the `System.gc` call, then the last size reported remains `3` rather than the expected `2`.

You can even see this behavior when [running this code live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JAs936). Notice how the last item below is `3` but above is `2`.

> Size before adding: 0
>
> Size after adding 4 items: 4
>
> Size after removing item # 3: 3
>
> Size after making garbage of item # 2: 3

Comment: _Yes, keys cleared after garbage is actually collected_ - is not entirely correct. When GC clears a weak reference, it posts an "event" to a reference queue - that process is asynchronous, and even if GC has "cleared" your keys, WeakHashMap still has a strong reference to the value. The actual clean-up happens when 1) GC has posted the event to the reference queue (you have no control of _when_ this happens) 2) you call any _other_ method on the `WeakHashMap` - that will do the needed clean-up.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks for the details. Can you cite a source for this info, for further reading?

Comment: I've posted an answer with some details and comments, should be obvious what is going on IMO...

Answer (score 2):

When [garbage-collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) clears a [weak reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference), it posts an "event" to a reference queue. That process is [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)), and even if GC has "cleared" your keys, [`WeakHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) still has a strong reference to the value. The actual clean-up happens when:

1. Garbage Collector has posted the event to the reference queue (you have no control of when this happens).
2. You call any other method on the `WeakHashMap` - that will do the needed clean-up.

Here is an example to show what is going on.

```
public class WeakHashMapInAction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Key key = new Key();
        KeyMetadata keyMeta = new KeyMetadata("keyMeta");

        WeakHashMap<Key, KeyMetadata> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
        map.put(key, keyMeta);

        // wrap the key into a weakReference
        WeakReference<Key> keyReference = new WeakReference<>(key);

        // force key to be GC-ed
        key = null;
        for (; keyReference.get() != null; ) {
            System.gc();
        }

        // at this point keyReference::get returns null,
        // meaning the GC has reclaimed "key";
        // that does NOT mean WeakHashMap removed that entry though

        // you can enable this code to see that "not yet collected" is not printed at all
        // since you are giving enough time for the Reference thread to post to that ReferenceQueue
        // LockSupport.parkNanos(10000000);

        while (map.size() == 1) {
            // if you run this enough times, you will see this sometimes is printed
            // even if WeakHashMap::size calls "expungeStaleEntries" internally
            // it does not mean that the event to the queue was pushed in time
            // by the Reference thread
            System.out.println("not yet collected");
        }

        System.out.println("collected");

    }


    static class Key {

    }

    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class KeyMetadata {
        private final String someInfo;

        // Constructor.
        KeyMetadata ( String someInfo ) { this.someInfo = someInfo; }
    }

}
```